# Express Middleware Use() Function

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

If I have the JS code below:

```
app.use('/assets', function(req, res, next){
    express.static(__dirname + '/public')
    next(); 
});

app.get('/assets', function(req, res) {
    res.send('<html><head><link href="/assets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head><body><h1>Hello World!s</h1></body></html>');
});
```

Basically in the `get` function I am referencing a static file in the public folder called style.css from the link tag in res.send(...) html text. Now in the HTML when the browser sees this **link tag** it will make a HTTP request for localhost:3000/assets/style.css. So if it sees anything after the /assets it will look for that file (style.css in this case) in the public folder because that is what I put in the `express.static(__dirname + '/public')` function. But for some reason the css is not working on the HTML element's.

In the style.css I am just setting the font size to `200px;`

```
body {
        font-size: 200px;
}
```

I am also very confused on which callback is called first and the order:

I know that for express in terms of middleware we are able to do something in between the request and response. I am a little confused on when the callback methods to the function `use` and `get` are called.

So first off the browser would make a request to the server. Then when the server gets the request will it call the callback in the `use` function first? Then run the code inside of the `use` callback. Then when it calls next() it will go to the `get` function and run the code inside of there. Is that execution correct?

Comment: I believe that this depends on content-type of the request. So if it is text/html your get route should be called. The order is from the top to bottom. And your app.use is actually wrong it should be `app.use('/assets', express.static(...));` the 'next' is called internally if the path doesn't match any static file

Comment: Hi! When you say order is from top to bottom. I don't really understand that. What is at the top and what is at the bottom?

Comment: Express processes app.use app.get etc in the order you have written them in your file from top to bottom. In your case app.use is above app.get so app.use is called first

Comment: Ohh I see. Ok Thanks! Also when is a case when I would have to use app.use with the callback function rather than using app.use('/assets', express.static(...));

Comment: Whenever you write a middleware. I use it for logging request url to console so I do something like `console.log(req.url); next();` you can assign some values to req or res. The function express.static() actually return a function that looks like the callback `function(req,res,next){...}` you just don't see it

Comment: Oh ok! Thanks for the help!